# where do i put the javascript using asp master page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, position

So here I want to put some JavaScript for my carousel from Twitter bootstrap, the problem is, it seems having no effect no matter where I put it, I already made sure the id matches. Here's the code (note: I'm using master page)

```
$(‘.carousel‘).carousel
({
    interval: 1000
})
```

I put it in `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>` which I believe is the head, but it still not working, any advice on how to do this?

Comment: have you got the correct javascript references in the page too? if you viewsource on the page, you will see what's being rendered.

Comment: Are you trying to put this code in the master page itself, or a content page based on the the master page?

Comment: @RobEarl, I noticed you altered the quotes in the code (in your edit), could this actually be the issue?

Comment: @christiandev, I changed them as an edit I was reviewing appeared to be changing them wrongly. Reviewing the history I see they were originally like that so I've put them back.

Comment: @RobEarl, I see - I thought the code was being cleaned up :)

Comment: @christiandev yes, i have the correct jscript reference

Comment: Are you sure control is not going in your event. Try putting alert first.

Comment: @Jamiec i planned to put it in the content page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your master page has something like this in it:

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" />        
</head>
```

Then any page which is based on this master page you can indeed put anything inside `<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server"> </asp:Content>` which you want to be placed in the `<head>` section of your web page. This routinely contains bits of javascript, however in order for jQuery to do it's think you must wait until the document is ready:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel
        ({
            interval: 1000
        });
});
</script>
```

As an additional point (or, stab in the dark) you mention in your question "I already made sure the id matches" however you have not referenced any element by ID (except perhaps the `ContentPlaceholder`); your jQuery code references an element by class name `.carousel`.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in child page in which you have implemented `carousel`. also make sure to reference `JQuery` and `carousel` script file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 1000
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: good answer, too bad someone else answered it first, thank you though.

Comment: @AbieGiordano, I have answered approx 500 milliseconds earlier, but Jamiec answer is better than mine in terms of explanation

Comment: oh, i didn't noticed it, sorry mister.

Comment: Its all in the milliseconds :) Hopefully my +1 makes up for the lost 5 rep

Comment: @Jamiec, you gave better explanation you deserve that and if I am in place of Abie Giordano I would have done the same thing.